# Can't sort a list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort and reverse a list as following:

```
train_eigen_pairs = [(np.abs(train_eigen_vals[i]),train_eigen_vec[:,i]) for i in range(len(train_eigen_vals))]
train_eigen_pairs.sort(reverse=True)
# Also tried :
reversed(sorted(train_eigen_pairs))
# and 
reversed(train_eigen_pairs.sort())
```

With all three variants I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**Update**

After retrying, I think the solution to the problem will b, to sort the tuple based on the first column :
here is what I've tried, but the sorting take too long.

```
sorted( train_eigen_pairs,key=lamda train_eignen_pairs: train_eigen_pairs[0], reverse=True)
```

Apparently I'm missing something, because it crashes the IDE.the first column contain float values, the second complex ones.

```
train_eigen_pairs[0][0]  is a float 
train_eigen_pairs[0][1]  is a complex vector
```

Any idea how can I solve this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to pass a key to sort by. This may be a lambda. You're sorting a list of tuples `(np.abs(train_eigen_vals[i]),train_eigen_vec[:,i])`. However the second item of the tuple is a numpy array and python can't implicitly sort it as is.

Comment: Comparing two arrays produces an array of booleans, not a single boolean. This happens if the tuple comparison compares the second element of each tuple.

Comment: @chepner sorry but I can't follow what do you mean I can see  complex number as values in train_eigen_pairs. I want to sort them based  on the value of train_eigen_vals and than reverse the sorting

Comment: @OluwafemiSule & chepner I've updated the question

Comment: Say you compare two tuples, `(1, np.array([1,2,3]) < (1, np.array([3,2,1])`. Since `1 == 1`, the result of the comparison will be the result of comparing the two numpy arrays, which is going to `np.array([True, False, False])`. *That* array doesn't have a defined Boolean value, which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After  trying multiple variants , here is the one that worked, I hope it may help someone out there :

```
train_eigen_pairs.sort(key=lambda x:x[0],reverse=True)
```

Comment: `sorted(train_eigen_pairs, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)`
this also works in same way.